# ResearchKit headers not able to import in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, researchkit

I am making an app using the ResearchKit framework of Apple.

I have followed the installation guide of `ResearchKit` on GitHub and added the files to my project. Now when I am trying to import the header files of this framework, I get an error:

> File not found

*What I did:*

I created a new project named `CreatingTasks.xcodeproj`.

Then I added `ResearchKit` files by dragging the `researchKit.xcodeproj` in my navigation controller, and embedding the `ResearchKit` framework in embedded binaries.

Now I want to create a simple task in my existing view controller but I am unable to import the header files.

Comment: Can you provide some parts of code for better understanding. Thanks

Comment: the problem is very tiny. I created a new project named CreatingTasks.xcodeproj . Then I added researchKit files by dragging the researchKit.xcodeproj in my navigation controller and embedding the researchkit framework in embedded binaries. Now I want to create a simple task in my existing view controller but I am unable to import the header files. here is the link of researchKit github, https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit   i used to add this framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build the ResearchKit target once first. Then you should be able to import ResearchKit. If that doesn't help, please post a project on GitHub and give us a link.